# Why don't xlinker's sum and checksum match? (IAR 5.40)

Tags: checksum, crc, iar

I am using IAR 5.40 and xlink to generate the checksum. The generated checksum and calculated checksum don't match. Here is how my memory map looks like:

```
Symbol       Checksum  Memory  Start   End    Initial value
------       --------  ------  -----   ---    -------------
__checksum    0xd973    CODE   4400 - FF7D    0x0000 (#0x0000)
                        CODE   FF80 - 243FF
```

The `__checksum` is located at `FF7E - FF7F`

I am using IAR provided checksum calculator:

```
sum = fast_crc16(0, (unsigned char *)0x4400, (0xff7d - 0x4400 + 1));
```

The `sum` and `__checksum` don't match. Looks like I am missing something. Need Help!!